# The instance variable doesn't update

Tags: python, oop

I can't figure out why the variable in the class doesn't update.

```
class Pile:
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards

    def __str__(self):
        result = ' '.join(self.cards)
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Pile({self.cards})'

    def flip(self):
        self.cards.reverse()
        return eval(f'Pile({self.cards})')
```

This is a part of my code.
And when I run this code below,

```
cards = Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
print(cards)
# AH 3S KC
cards
# Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
cards.flip().flip()
# Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
print(cards)
```

I expected 'AH 3S KC' but I got 'KC 3S AH'. 'KC 3S AH' is the result of **cards.flip()**.

I think **cards.flip().flip()** this part doesn't work becuase when I wrote **cards.flip()** and again **cards.flip()**, that works exactly what I wanted to be. I don't know what is the problem of this. Could you explain about this? Thank you for reading.

Comment: You flip your pile TWICE so its back to where it was - what is your problem with that? Why do you return a new object from your flip method? eval creates a new object?

Comment: There is no class variable involved, just an instance variable. I don't understand the strange `eval()`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner When I print cards, I got 'KC 3S AH' which is the result of flip once. I used eval to return python representation. I'm confused with how to return python repr.

Comment: @guidot Sorry. I'll edit to instance variable.

Comment: Thank you guys the problem was the wrong usage of eval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `eval` function in your `flip()` method. Reverse the `Pile` instance in the `flip` method and then return it.

**Code**

```
class Pile:
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards

    def __str__(self):
        result = ' '.join(self.cards)
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Pile({self.cards})'

    def flip(self):
        self.cards.reverse()
        return self

cards = Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
print(cards)
# AH 3S KC
cards
# Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
cards.flip().flip()

# Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
print(cards)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You don't need a call to eval(), nor do you need any f-strings there. Just create an instance in the return statement of the flip() method.

Comment: this will create a new Pile and return it from flip() - this one has the same internal values of the once flipped cards. cards will still be only once flipped. So `cards.flip().flip()` will flip the orignal cards once, create another Pile, flip those internal values and return yet another Pile without flipping back the orignal `cards`. as the OP was surprised his original cards did not get twice flipped, this seems not to be the correct way to do it - but as he accepted it, he might still want it like that. who knows ...

Comment: Initially, I thought the OP wants to create another instance in the flip() method with a reversed list. However, I updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your *flip* method must operate on an instance of *Pile* . Therefore, *flip* must return the instance.

```
class Pile:
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards

    def __str__(self):
        result = ' '.join(self.cards)
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Pile({self.cards})'

    def flip(self):
        self.cards.reverse()
        return self
```

When I run the example code, I get the initial list, which is what I would expect from a double flip:

```
cards = Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
print(cards)
# AH 3S KC
cards
# Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
cards.flip().flip()
# Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])
print(cards)
```

output:

```
AH 3S KC
AH 3S KC
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused with the usage of eval() function. Now I got it!

Answer (score 1):

You do not flip the same object twice, but return independant copies of your first object:

You have a instance of `Pile` called `cards`. You call `flip()` on it. It reverses the `cards` internal cardstack and returns `eval(f'Pile({self.cards})')`.

`eval` creates a **NEW object** with your current `self.cards` as inital parameters - that you then flip again (still the other object, which creates yet another one on *eval*) and then you throw away all the created objects because you never STORE them anywhere.

You then print the (once flipped) orignal `cards` instance.

```
cards = Pile(['AH', '3S', 'KC'])

print(cards, id(cards))

cards2 = cards.flip() # you flip this another time w/o storing it anywhere

print(cards2, id(cards2))  # print with obj id to see its different
print(cards, id(cards))    # print with obj id to see its different
```

Output:

```
AH 3S KC 140645422863584 # cards
KC 3S AH 140645422863976 # result of cards.flip() as new object 
KC 3S AH 140645422863584 # your original cards once flipped
```

You want:

```
def flip(self):
    self.cards.reverse()
    return self  # return yourself for chaining
```

Read about [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) in the doc.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. I totally got it!